# Python Dictionary re

Tags: regex, python-2.7, dictionary

As you can see in code using regular expression script searches for words in txt and puts them to dictionary like this:

```
set(["['card', 'port']"])
set(["['onu_id', 'remote_id']"])
set(["['card', 'port', 'onu_id']"])
set(["['card', 'port', 'onu_id']"])
set(["['remote_id']"])
set(["['remote_id']"])
set(["['card', 'port', 'onu_id']"])
```

Problem is that i need to input values to them by hand and remove everything except keys(card,port,onu_id,remote_id)(remove: set(["[' to see everything clearly:

```
 dict{card:1, port:5, onu_id:3, remote_id:16568764}
```

To look like this and be easy to read.
Here is my code:

```
import re, string
with open("conf.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
for line in text:
    match = re.findall(r'_\$(\w+)',line)
    if match:
        dict = {str(match)}
        print dict
```

part of input file:

```
interface gpon-olt_1/_$card/_$port
onu _$onu_id type ZTE-F660 pw _$remote_id vport-mode gemport
no lock
no shutdown
exit

interface gpon-onu_1/_$card/_$port:\_$onu_id
exit
interface gpon-onu_1/_$card/_$port:\_$onu_id
name ONU-_$remote_id 102211+1
description 
vport-mode gemport def-map-type 1:1
```

Comment: Would be easier if you showed a part of the input file.
Also, you are not creating a dictionary, but a set.

Comment: edited so you could see part of input file